# Getting heading for a table from JSON data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have following type of JSON Data

```
[
{"Col1": "Server1", "Col2": "57", "Col3": "Create", "Col4": "Details" },
{"Col1": "Server2", "Col2": "27", "Col3": "Create", "Col4": "Details" },
{"Col1": "Server3", "Col2": "89", "Col3": "Create", "Col4": "Details" },
{"Col1": "Server4", "Col2": "75", "Col3": "Create", "Col4": "Details" },
{"Col1": "Server5", "Col2": "77", "Col3": "Create", "Col4": "Details" },
{"Col1": "Server6", "Col2": "55", "Col3": "Create", "Col4": "Details" }
]
```

Now what I need is Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4 in some array so that I can put those as headings to the dynamic table that I need to create.. 
Any idea on how to get these values in an array?

Comment: I just need heading names e.g Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 in the above stated example

Comment: Do you need each one of them in a separate array??

Comment: each one?? I just need COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 in a array, so I that I can use these as headings for my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each loop` to iterate and store the values into an array.

```
var col1Array= [];
var col2Array= [];
var col3Array= [];
var col4Array= [];

var headerArray = [];
// Select the first Object in the Array
// and iterate over it
$.each(data[0] , function(key, value){
   headerArray.push(key)
});

console.log(headerArray);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RUemz/3/)**

Comment: I guess u misunderstood the question. I just need to fetch header names from JSON data.. not the values for each header..So in an ideal scenarion I need an output as ["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"]...